# Sum of integer and timestamp

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've this query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8260a/19

And I need to convert to DQL.

I tried

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Scheduling');
                /* @var $qb \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder */
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
                $qb->where('a.date <= :date')
                        ->andWhere('a.date + a.duration=> :finalDate')
                        ->andWhere('a.chair = :chair')
                        ->setParameter('date', $scheduling->getDate())
                        ->setParameter('finalDate', $finalDate)
                        ->setParameter('chair', $scheduling->getChair());
```

Then I got the error: timestamp without time zone + integer.

Comment: The error suggests that you can't add an integer to a timestamp, which is generally true, but support (and errant support) is uneven. You *can* add a value of type "interval" to a timestamp. In other words, although it doesn't make sense to add 3 to '2014-06-15 08:00', it *does* make sense to add 3 minutes to '2014-06-15 08:00'. (Or 3 seconds, or 3 hours, or 3 days. That's why sensible systems reject a bare 3.)

Comment: So I have to write native SQL?

Comment: No, but ->andWhere('a.date + INTERVAL a.duration MINUTE => :finalDate')

Comment: or DAY or HOUR or whatever ;)

Comment: Right, but it also occurs to me that the error isn't about that. The MySQL Timestamp datatype expects a Timezone, and it can't do that to just a datetime - the comparison is incomplete. Is there a function that would also generate current timezone and send it into :date?

Comment: @JaazCole I tried what you said, but I got Syntax Error after INTERVAL:
`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 105: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'a'`

Comment: @JaazCole My real database is Timestamp without timezone (Postgres)

Comment: I tried it in sqlfiddle and it works...but then again, there may be postgres syntax differences that I'm unfamiliar with, sorry.

Comment: @LeonardoPinheiro: No, you shouldn't have to write SQL. In php, you have a DateInterval class.